# How do I fix the syntax error at "TO" in \copy?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm trying to copy the results of a SQL query to a CSV file with \copy. However, I am getting a syntax error at TO and I can't quire figure out why.

Note that executing the SQL query works in psql, but I get an error when I try to export the query's results out of \copy into a CSV file.

```
\COPY
(SELECT 
event_number,
event_type,
unit,
received,
split_part(entry::TEXT,' ',1)entry_year,
split_part(entry::TEXT,' ',2)entry_time,
split_part(dispatch::TEXT,' ',1)dispatch_year,
split_part(dispatch::TEXT,' ',2)dispatch_time,
split_part(ack::TEXT,' ',1)ack_year,
split_part(ack::TEXT,' ',2)ack_time,
enroute,
split_part(onscene::TEXT,' ',1)onscene_year,
split_part(onscene::TEXT,' ',2)onscene_time,
split_part(to_hospital::TEXT,' ',1)to_hospital_year,
split_part(to_hospital::TEXT,' ',2)to_hospital_time,
at_hospital,
return_to_qrtrs,
split_part(available_in_qrtrs::TEXT,' ',1)available_in_qrtrs_year,
split_part(available_in_qrtrs::TEXT,' ',2)available_in_qrtrs_time,
split_part(last_col::TEXT,' ',1)last_col_year,
split_part(last_col::TEXT,' ',2)last_col_time
FROM import.oems)
TO '/Users/ctoner/Desktop/oems/foia_190910/formatoems.csv' WITH CSV DELIMETER ',' HEADER;

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "TO"
LINE 24: TO '/Users/ctoner/Desktop/oems/foia_190910/formatoems.csv'
```

Comment: there is an extra closing bracket `)` in your code near line `FROM import.oems` .

Comment: But doesn't that single closing bracket correspond to the bracket at the beginning of '(SELECT'? Or is there another extra bracket I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

There's a Typo in your query

at line `TO '/Users/ctoner/Desktop/oems/foia_190910/formatoems.csv' WITH CSV DELIMETER ',' HEADER;`

Replace `DELIMETER` with `DELIMITER`

Also, the documentation says the file should be present on the server already.

Comment: Thanks! Still getting hung up on this syntax error though. :/

Comment: is `'/Users/ctoner/Desktop/oems/foia_190910/formatoems.csv'` your full path ?

Comment: I struck the brackets from the SQL query, but now i'm getting a syntax error at `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "TO"
LINE 24: TO`

Comment: Yes `'/Users/ctoner/Desktop/oems/foia_190910/formatoems.csv'` is my full path. Do I need to create a CSV file to dump the data in, or should the program do it automatically?

Comment: are you doing it in pgAdmin ? you can just do with `COPY` comand ?

Comment: pgAdmin tells me that 'HINT:  COPY TO instructs the PostgreSQL server process to write a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy'

Comment: `psql -U <user> -d <db_name> -c "Copy (Select * From foo_table LIMIT 10) To STDOUT With CSV HEADER DELIMITER ',';" > foo_data.csv`  try using this from command line client. And change necessary info>